# How to display a variables from digits in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, cout

I have 4 variables called: number, x , y, z.

```
x = 1,
y = 2,
z = 3
```

I would like the variable number to be able take the values of x, y and z and  be able to display value of 123

I have tried this so far:

```
number = x + y + z; but the answer is 6.
```

or

```
number = x << y << z; but the output is not what I want.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What type are those variables?

Answer (score 5):

in C++:

```
cout << x << y << z
```

In C:

```
printf("%d%d%d", x, y, z);
```

Or to put them in a string:

```
ostringstream convert;   // stream used for the conversion

convert << x << y << z; 

std::string result = convert.str();
```

Comment: Hard to tell when he says wants to "display".  Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) to convert the `int` to `string`, then the `+` operator acts as a concatenation operation.

```
#include <string>

std::string concatenated = std::to_string(x) + std::to_string(y) + std::to_string(z);
std::cout << concatenated;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may want to convert the characters to strings, perform the string addition, and then convert back to numbers.

This link should help:
[http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9645/]

Answer (score 0):

You have plenty of ways to get your result :

- numerically : `number = x * 100 + y * 10 + z`
- string concatenation as shown by Cyber
- directly using characters :

  ```
  char resul[4];
  resul[0] = '0' + x;
  resul[1] = '0' + y;
  resul[2] = '0' + z;
  resul[3] = '\0';
  ```

and probably many others ...